# Use regular Rails DateHelper with Best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, best-in-place

I'm using `best_in_place` gem for my app and I need to use `:date` field, but problem is that I can't use jquery UI-css because I have made custom css and it will mess with it.

How can I use regular Rails `DateHelper` instead of `jquery datepicker` for `best_in_place` date fields?

Comment: easier option would be to see whats under the hood of DateHepler, and change source of best_in_place gem. Its source pretty easy to read